# I get error saying 'no module named selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, import

I have tried to install `selenium` multiple times.

I typed in all these below.

`python3 -m pip install selenium`
`pip3 install selenium`
`pip install selenium`

etc

I can tell it has been installed by trying `pip list` and it's on the list but still it's not running and showing the error 'no module named 'selenium''

Any help?

Comment: If you're using conda environment, can you try using `conda install` ?

Comment: How are you importing the module?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver ///////////
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys ///////// this is how I import!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try printing "pip3 freeze" in ubuntu to get list of packages installed?. Add them in Question. So, We can help.

and try this one

```
python3 -m pip install
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install selenium
pip freeze #to check all installed packages
```

Comment: I have just tried this. It shows pip, selenium, setup tools and urllib3 on the list. But still it's not working...